# Proftpd: only allow one address

Tags: debian, ftp

I am searching for it on Google, but i didn't find anything. Is there a way tho set up proftpd that it will only accept a connection on ftp.website.ext and not on website.ext or test.website.ext

I am running proftpd on Debian 5

Tom

Comment: In your example does ftp.website.ext and test.website.ext map to different IP addresses?

Comment: no, to the same

Answer (score 1):

I think the last part of [this article](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_SocketBindTight.html) may help?  It discusses listening only on specific IP addresses.

From other repsonses you've made, it seems you want it to be hostname based, and the IP addresses for these hosts are all the same.  The answer is, no, you cannot do that, sorry.  FTP is an old, old protocol and does not handle hostnames.  The client doesn't have any mechanism to send the requested hostname along, and the server has no facility to accept it.

Comment: the article seems to point to using different IP address's, rather than host names. If all the hostnames are on the same IP then I don't think it will work.

Comment: FTP is address based.  It can't be made hostname based as the server does not know what hostname the client is requesting.  I will update my answer to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of VirtualHost and Default Address blocks much in the same way you'd do Apache:

http://proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_VirtualHost.html
http://proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultAddress.html

```
DefaultAddress 1.2.3.4 ftp.website.com

<VirtualHost website.com www.website.com>
 ...config stuff...
 <Limit LOGIN>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from none
  Deny from all
 </Limit>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ftp.website.com>
  ...do FTP configs...
</VirtualHost>
```

Untested by me but looks like it should work.